# Failed to deploy Laravel 5.2 with subdomains GoDaddy, AWS and Routes

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, deployment

It is NOT on a Shared Server (cPanel)

What am I doing wrong? I have an application in Laravel 5.2 with two
areas (BackEnd and FrontEnd), which works correctly locally, defining
Virtual Host, but when I try to deploy to a production server, it
shows a blank page. The domain is in GoDaddy with two subdomains
pointing to an Ubuntu 18 Server in AWS (php 5.6).

Any idea why it does not redirect to direct routes? I appreciate any help.

site.mydominio.com Redireccionado a
http://ipserveramazon/vouchervalidation/public
admin.mydominio.com Redireccionado a
http://ipserveramazon/vouchervalidation/public

app\http\routes.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
return redirect()->route('home.index');

//die('Working');
});
Route::get('/frontend', function () {
return redirect()->route('home.index');
});
Route::get('/backend', function () {
return redirect()->route('dashboard.index');
});
```

Routes FrontEnd:

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Modules\Frontend\Http\Controllers',
'domain'     => 'site.'.getenv('HOST_NAME'), 'middleware' => ['web']],
function(){
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');

Route::any('/', function(){
return redirect()->route('home.index');
});

Route::group(array('prefix' => 'home'), function(){
Route::get('index', array('as' => 'home.index', 'uses' =>
'HomeController@index'));
});
...
});
```

Routes BackEnd:

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Modules\Backend\Http\Controllers',
'domain' => 'admin.'.getenv('HOST_NAME'), 'middleware' =>
['web','auth']], function(){

Route::get('backend', array('as' => 'backend.index', 'uses' =>
'BackendController@index'));
Route::get('dashboard', array('as' => 'dashboard.index', 'uses' =>
'DashboardController@index'));

Route::group(array('prefix' => 'dashboard'), function(){
Route::get('get-documents-chart/{year}', array('as' =>
'dashboard.get-documents-chart', 'uses' =>
'DashboardController@getDocumentsChart'));
});
…
});
```

*.htacess file in public folder : *

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /var/www/html/vouchervalidation/public/
   # change above to your site i.e.,  RewriteBase /whatever/public/

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
*apache2.conf file in /etc/apache2 : *

ServerName localhost

Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}
Timeout 300
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 5
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}
HostnameLookups Off
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
LogLevel warn
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf
Include ports.conf

<Directory />
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory /usr/share>
AllowOverride None
Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/html/vouchervalidation/public>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
*000-default.conf in etc/apache2/sites-enabled : *

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/vouchervalidation/public
<Directory /var/www/html/vouchervalidation/public>
Allowoverride All
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost site.protelcotelsa.com:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ServerName site.protelcotelsa.com
ServerAlias site.protelcotelsa.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/vouchervalidation/public
<Directory /var/www/html/vouchervalidation/public>
Allowoverride All
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost admin.protelcotelsa.com:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ServerName admin.protelcotelsa.com
ServerAlias admin.protelcotelsa.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/vouchervalidation/public
<Directory /var/www/html/vouchervalidation/public>
Allowoverride All
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I tried the following:

sudo a2enmod rewrite

sudo chgrp -R www-data storage bootstrap/cache

sudo chmod -R ug+rwx storage bootstrap/cache

I tried passing the contents of the public folder to / var / www /
html / and editing the files index.php, .htacess, resulting in the
same problem.

composer install --optimize-autoloader --no-dev

php artisan config:cache

php artisan route:cache

php artisan vendor:publish

sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf

sudo a2ensite 000-default.conf

I changed the ubuntu server to 14.04, resulting in the same problem as
the blank page.

add die('Working'); to routes and good

http://3.14.103.54/vouchervalidation/public/index.php/frontend (same problemt)

http://3.14.103.54/vouchervalidation/public/index.php/backend (same problemt)

...

but without results, your help, please

Comment: Take out server.php from public folder to the main folder and rename to index.php. Also, take a .htaccess file from public folder to the main folder.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I followed his steps, but it still does not work, same result!                   ubuntu@ip-172-31-17-235:/var/www/html/vouchervalidation$ ls -a
.   .env          .gitattributes  .htaccess  artisan    composer.json  config    gulpfile.js  modules       phpunit.xml  readme.md  server.php  tests
..  .env.example  .gitignore      app        bootstrap  composer.lock  database  index.php    package.json  public       resources  storage     vendor

Comment: how do I configure the dns, for this case?